# How to set rules for inserting new values into SQLite database on Android?

Tags: android

For example, I inserted 2 rows into database: first with "1" _ID and second with "2" _ID. If I delete the second row and insert a new one it will have "2" _ID again. Is it possible to set rule for database which increase _ID always? In my case, a new one will have "3" _ID instead of "2". Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `AUTOINCREMENT` keyword on your `_ID` column. This will guarantee that automatically chosen ROWIDs will be increasing.

From the [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html):

> Note that "monotonically increasing" does not imply that the ROWID
>   always increases by exactly one. One is the usual increment. However,
>   if an insert fails due to (for example) a uniqueness constraint, the
>   ROWID of the failed insertion attempt might not be reused on
>   subsequent inserts, resulting in gaps in the ROWID sequence.
>   AUTOINCREMENT guarantees that automatically chosen ROWIDs will be
>   increasing but not that they will be sequential.